# Remove an clicked item from listview android

Tags: android

```
public class ListCategorieActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
public static String RISULTATO = "RISULTATO";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_categorie);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(ListCategorieActivity.this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent();
    String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
    bundle.putString(RISULTATO,some_array[position]);
    mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
    finish();
}
```

The Activity ListCategorieActivity show a clickable list of item. My task is eliminate (delete) the item from the listview when the item is clicked. How I can accomplish this task with this code?

activity_list_categorie.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.utente.myapplication.ListCategorieActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/sections" >
</ListView>
```

array.xml:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="sections">
    <item >OG 1</item>
    <item >OG 2</item>
    <item >OG 3</item>
    <item >OG 4</item>
    <item >OG 5</item>
    <item >OG 6</item>
    <item >OG 7</item>
    <item >OG 8</item>
    <item >OG 9</item>
    <item >OG 10</item>
    <item >OG 11</item>
    <item >OG 12</item>
    <item >OG 13</item>
    <item >OS 1</item>
    <item >OS 2-A</item>
    <item >OS 2-B</item>
    <item >OS 3</item>
    <item >OS 4</item>
    <item >OS 5</item>
    <item >OS 6</item>
    <item >OS 7</item>
    <item >OS 8</item>
    <item >OS 9</item>
    <item >OS 10</item>
    <item >OS 11</item>
    <item >OS 12-A</item>
    <item >OS 12-B</item>
    <item >OS 13</item>
    <item >OS 14</item>
    <item >OS 15</item>
    <item >OS 16</item>
    <item >OS 17</item>
    <item >OS 18-A</item>
    <item >OS 18-B</item>
    <item >OS 19</item>
    <item >OS 20-A</item>
    <item >OS 20-B</item>
    <item >OS 21</item>
    <item >OS 22</item>
    <item >OS 23</item>
    <item >OS 24</item>
    <item >OS 25</item>
    <item >OS 26</item>
    <item >OS 27</item>
    <item >OS 28</item>
    <item >OS 29</item>
    <item >OS 30</item>
    <item >OS 31</item>
    <item >OS 32</item>
    <item >OS 33</item>
    <item >OS 34</item>
    <item >OS 35</item>
</string-array>
```

I think I not using an adapter.It is correct?

Comment: Post full `ListCategorieActivity` code

Comment: I have post full code of ListCategorieActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add listview.getAdapter.remove(position); in the OnItemClick method. I suppose you are using an ArrayAdapter though.

EDIT

I'm afraid my explanation was pretty sloppy. The OnItemClick method has 4 arguments: AdapterView l is the ListView whose children are being observed and int position is the child position in the ListView; if (and only if) the list adapter is an ArrayAdapter object, the remove(Object item) method is available and can be used to delete a list item; in order to get the right Object, one must call

Object item = ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

to get the Object to delete; then, the ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter()).remove(item); can be called to remove the selected object.

Comment: .removeViewAt(int) or .removeView(View) is not supported in AdapterView.

Comment: That's why I call remove() from the AdapterList object, which I said I assume is ArrayAdapter. But you are somehow right, because ArrayLists only support remove(Object o), so overloading the remove() method is necessary in this case, or a getChildAtPosition(position) and then calling remove().

Comment: I can't call listview.getAdapter.remove(position) in the OnItemClick method. listview is not in the scope of OnItemClick method.

Comment: You have an AdapterView object as argument of OnItemClick.

Comment: And I can't call listview.getAdapter.remove(position) beacause remove is not supported.

Comment: Well, If you are not using an ArrayAdapter it is indeed not supported :) I hope you are not calling getAdapter though, because my example lacks parenthesis: it would be getAdapter().

Comment: if i call l.getAdapter().remove(position); remove is signed in red in Android Studio

Comment: Yes, that's true, the right signature is remove(Object o); I wrote somewhere up here that you need to retrieve the Object with a l.getChildAtPosition(position) and then pass it to remove() method, in order to work. Sorry for the messy explanation!

Comment: ... yes, that's what I just said; first of all, is your adapter an ArrayAdapter? if so, cast the adapter before calling remove; ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter()).remove(item); item is the object from the ArrayAdapter, which you can get calling Object item = ((ListView)l).getChildAtPosition(position); straighter than this I don't think I can tell.

Comment: I my list of methods there is l.getItemIdAtPosition(position); but not there is l.getChildAtPosition(position)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused in the process; forget getChild excetera, it was ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter).getItem(position); I don't really know why I insisted with l.getChild, since it would have returned a View object and not the item you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry Stg I dont understand what I do write.
I try
int myposition = ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
but dont work.

Comment: Nope, position is already the position you need; through getItem(int position) you get an Object stored into the ArrayAdapter, so try with Object item = ((ArrayAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getItem(position);

Answer (score 0):

You can put string resource into Arraylist, and simply use `myArray.remove(position)` method to delete an element in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

Remove the  item from the list using the remove() method of your ArrayAdapter.

```
Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
```

Or modify the ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged().

```
arrayList.remove([index]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: sorry, you can use the variable of my code? I dont have anyarrayAdapter and I dont have any arrayList, I dont understand